# JQuery Select on change code organization

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-organization

I am working on an application where the page has multiple images that are clickable, and a form text field that is editable, and all of these fire a Jquery functions with Ajax calls, and everything is in a JS file.  Everything is working.

However, I know have a different form that has a SELECT box, and I want it to also fire a function/Ajax call when it is changed.  I can't even get a simple alert to happen.

I am just wondering, do I possibly have this in the wrong location or something like that. This is my first foray into JQuery, and I am working by trial and error and tutorials, but there does not seem to be anything about code organization for functionality.

Side note: I can get an onChange event on the SELECT to fire when doing 'onChange="alert("Hello");'

HTML Code

```
            <form name="RankingForm" id="RankingForm">
                <td style="color: white;">
                    <select name="Ranking" id="Ranking" >
                        <option value="4" selected>Open</option>
                        <option value="3" >Advanced</option>
                        <option value="2" >Intermediate</option>
                        <option value="1" >Beginner</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </form>
```

Jquery JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var str = this.ID;

  $("input").focusout(function() { 
    $.ajax ({
      WORKING CODE
    })
  });

  $("img").click(function(){
    if (this.id.split('_')[0] == 'Favorite') {
        $.ajax ({
          WORKING CODE
      })
    }
    else if (this.id.split('_')[0] == 'Sent') {
      $.ajax ({
        WORKING CODE
      })
    }
    else if (this.id.split('_')[0] == 'Flash') {
      $.ajax ({
        WORKING CODE
      })
    }
  });
});

$('select[name=Ranking]').on("change", function () {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    //NOT WORKING
    alert("Hello");
    //ALSO NOT WORKING
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the location is wrong, the change listener is outside the `.ready(..)` callback function. You can have it like that because you're setting the listener using `.on(..)` but you'll have to call `.on(..)` on an object that is in the DOM when the code is executed, something like

```
$(document).on('select[name=Ranking]', 'change', function(){
  ..
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Should this have been inside the .ready(..) instead?

Unfortunately, this did not work. Thanks

Comment: Moving this inside the .ready(..) function did work.  I guess need to do some research on having independent functions, rather than having one large function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the code solutions worked for me, but Titus had the answer in his comments text.

Moving this inside the .ready(..) function did work. I guess need to do some research on having independent functions, rather than having one large function.